# How can I execute a command and store the files in a folder using a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a large number of tif files.

```
a.tif
b.tif
axx.tif
auw.tif
```

I am trying to write a script that will

1. Search for all .tif files
2. Perform a gdal conversion
3. Store a new file with the same file name under a subdirectory named "subdir"

   ```
   #!/bin/csh

   list - ls *.tif

   for file in list
           gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4269 -te -130 20 -60 55 -tr 0.01 -0.01 oldfilename.tif subdir/oldfilename.tif
   ```

   done

How can I do this?

Comment: We won't just write the whole thing for you. Ask a *specific* question about the thing that will help you get pass the main thing that you don't know how to do.

Comment: @kaylum I think I have asked a specific question as well as provided code I have worked on so far.  I know how to search for the files, and do the gdal conversion. But I am not sure how to account for the filenames in Step 3.

Comment: Is there anywhere in your question that says that step 3 is what you are specifically asking about? You have dumped some code but have not explicitly referred to it and explained what it currently does and what is wrong/missing with that code.

Comment: Tag for one shell (or at least, shells from a single family) -- bash (from the POSIX sh family), *or* csh. They're entirely incompatible with each other, and folks who are fluent in one typically don't know the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using "list" to find the files, you can use the "find" command, here's how it's done:

```
find . -name "*.tif" -exec gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4269 -te -130 20 -60 55 -tr 0.01 -0.01 {} subdir/{} \;
```

Explanation:

The . stands for "current directory" the -name option search for files with names that match the given pattern.

The -exec option is used to run a command using the file "find" found. The {} stands for the "filename" that was found, and the command that has to be run needs to be followed by \;

I highly suggest you read the manual entry for find, as well as do some more research on the tools you have at your disposal when attempting to write a shell script.

Regards!